# deferred.notify not reaching destination

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, deferred

I have a directive that uses a service to fetch some data. The service uses a cache where possible.

If the data is in the cache the notify works perfectly. When fetching the data for the first time however the notify is triggered but the notification doesn't appear to be reaching the destination.

I've spent some time digging into it and can't figure out what's going wrong. Hoping it's a simple mistake.

Directive.

```
kitchenApp.directive(
'chunkViewer',
[
    'v10systemModel',
    function(v10systemModel) {
        return {
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                // attrs are all lower-case
                $scope.chunkID  = attrs.chunkid;
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                v10systemModel.fetchDocument($scope.state.systemID, $scope.state.bookID)
                    .then(null, null, function(doc) {
                        $scope.chunk = doc.getChunkContents($scope.chunkID);
                    });
            },
            templateUrl: '/views/v10/directives/chunk-viewer.html',
        };
}]);
```

Service (partial)

```
service.fetchDocument = function(systemID, docID) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (systemID === cachedSystemID && docID === cachedDocID) {
        $timeout(function() {
            //
            // this one works
            //
            deferred.notify(cachedDoc);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    if (cachedDocID) {
        v10firedocs.stopWatchingDocument(RPGS_COLLECTION, cachedSystemID, cachedDocID);
        cachedSystemID = cachedDocID = cachedDC = null;
    }

    v10firedocs.getDocument(RPGS_COLLECTION, systemID, docID)
        .then(null, null, function(docObject) {
            cachedDoc = docObject;
            cachedSystemID = systemID;
            cachedDocID = docID;

            //
            // this doesn't appear to work
            //
            return deferred.notify(docObject);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: why use `notify` instead of `resolve`? Also, should this `return deferred.notify(docObject);` contain `return`?

Comment: I'm using notify as the data source at the end of this chain might update at any time @tanmay

Comment: @axzr I'm not sure if anyone else has any idea what that means, but I don't. Could you please explain more clearly? Progress notifications are an extremely rarely used part of promises, and from your code above, I see no reason why using `.notify` would make sense here. Seems like you might be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @JLRishe - good shout. I'm using notify because the database might update "underneath" me. I'm using Firebase as a backend and I'm watching it for updates. When one comes through I want to update the view. Does that explain it better?